# Compress image up to maximum size(100kb) at NodeJS or React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, image-compression

I've researched and tried many libraries to achieve this. The main point of task is compressing images(jpeg or png) up to 100KB regardless its quality or resolution. It's fine how bad the quality and resolution are but the size should not larger than 100KB.

Could anyone give me any idea?

FYI, I tried `imagemin`, `compress-images` libraries but they didn't compress image much as I need the result smaller than 100KB. So even though I have 5MB image file, I want it compressed less than 100KB.

Comment: I've had good luck with libvips via Sharp:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Comment: Hi @Brad, sharp module also have some issues while installing. Have you faced any installation issue regarding dependency sharp module.

Comment: @AartiVerma No, I haven't.  Make sure you have build tools installed.